# java - connect parent and child IDs and make the full path directories

Tags: java, mysql

I have been given an answer in question:
[Create folders from folder id and parent id in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532130/create-folders-from-folder-id-and-parent-id-in-java)

It was very useful but I do not understand the last part of the answer:

"Finally, just grab the folder with id 0 and start building your Files on the disk, using folder.getChildren() as a convenient way to move down the tree. Check out the javadoc on the File object, you will particularly want to use the mkdirs() method."

I don't even know where to being to implement it. Does anyone understand it?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your tree of `Folder` instances has been built, the root of the tree is the `Folder` with ID 0.

Start with this folder, and create a directory in the file system for each of its children, recursively:

```
/**
 * Creates a directory in parentDirectory for every child of the given folder,
 * recursively.
 */
public void createDirectoriesForChildren(Folder folder, File parentDirectory) {
    for (Folder childFolder : folder.getChildren()) {
        File directory = new File(parentDirectory, childFolder.getName());
        directory.mkdirs();
        createDirectoriesForChildren(childFolder, directory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where about should I place this code? under:

for(Folder folder : data.values()) {
            int parentId = folder.getParentFolderId();
            Folder parentFolder = data.get(parentId);
            if(parentFolder != null)
               parentFolder.addChildFolder(folder);

        }

or in a new class (called MkDirs and call it with: new MkDirs();?

Thanks Again

Comment: Do what you prefer. It doesn't matter much. Just try to keep methods small, and to give them only one responsibility.

Comment: epic, I don not understand your code but am I able to just drop it in at the end without passing it anything?

Comment: Don't just drop it somewhere. Try to understand it. Read the documentation of the classes and methods it uses. There are just 4 lines, and they should be easy to understand. You need to understand what you're doing if you want to be a developer.

Comment: Ok, I am learning as much as I can as quick as I can. I'm a Linux systems admin by day but always trying to learn new skills. Thanks again